# Simple timespinner for jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spinner

I'm new to work in date and time, i need to create a time spinner for my application. i have used Google to get my requirement but didn't reach my requirement. i need one simple time spinner [like this sample](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time).But i need that TimeSpinner without using globalization.js.

Is there any way to get simple timeSpinner like the above link?

Comment: I think you can skip the Globalisation.js and just use the timespinner directly with .timespinner()

Comment: without globalization its not working fine.

Comment: have you tried http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=TimeSpinner&theme=metro-gray&dir=ltr&pitem=#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one Time spinner from **[HERE](https://github.com/JQFAQ/DateTimePicker/blob/master/TimeSpinner.js)**. Which is more useful. I hope that will help you more.